# Do health wells, chests, and other interactive objects that allies use count towards the achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Achievements such as "Slice of life" and "Chestmaster 2000" require that you interact with a certain number of interactive objects.  These objects appear to all players in co-op, and seem to benefit all players when any one player interacts with them.  So - when another player in my party interact with one of these objects, does it count towards my achievements?

> **Slice of Life**
>
> Use 50 Health wells
>
> **Chestmaster 2000**
>
> Open 2000 chests

Comment: I highly doubt that, but I have no proof :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Health Wells and chests only count for the person that opened them.

I just joined a multiplayer game to test this out.  I started at 37 chests and 5 health wells, and my friend had 78 chests and 10 health wells.  He opened a chest and, after a delay of 3 or 4 minutes, his updated to 79, while mine stayed at 37.  The next chest I opened, and after a delay mine incremented and his did not.  We found a pair of health wells, and noticed the same behavior.  After a few minute delay, the person who interacted with the object got credit while the other person did not.

Comment: Excellent research. A bummer, but thanks for checking it out.